# how to center two div in xs

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have two divs aligning one on the left and other on the right side. But i want that div to align center in small devices. How to center the two divs in bootstrap xs devices.

HTML Code

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <span class="search_title">Director <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <form class="form-group pull-right">
                <label>Categories &nbsp; </label>
                <select>
                    <option></option>
                    <option>Director</option>
                    <option>Producer</option>
                    <option>Actor</option>
                    <option>Actress</option>
                    <option>Child artist</option>
                </select>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS Code

```
.search_title {font-size:18px; padding:3px 15px; text-align:center; border:1px solid #ff6000;}
.search_title i {position:absolute; bottom:-13px; left:63px; color:#ff6000;}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "centering"? Do you still want a half of the screen width with a quarter margin left and right?

Comment: `<div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">` ??

Comment: There is a word 'Director'. In large devices alignment should be left but in small devices it has to automatically adjust to centre.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, on smaller screens each `<div class="col-md-6">` takes the whole width.

If you want each div a half of the screen width with a quarter margin left and right, then you can use an offset:

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-xs-offset-3 col-xs-6">
   ...
</div>
```